# Is there a way to see the actual mutated request Puppeteer is sending?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm mutating a request POST body content but on devtools I see the original request. Is there a way to see the content that I'm mutating? (I want to verify that the content I'm passing to the `request.continue` is actually working and sent to the server)

sample code:

```js
  page.on("request", request => {
    return request.continue({
          postData: "...some-overide..."
        });
  });
```

the full version of the code I've used is:

```js
import p from "puppeteer";

async function main() {
  const b = await p.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await b.newPage();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", request => {
    if (request.method() === "POST") {
      const postData = request.postData();
      if (postData.includes("&")) {
        console.log(request.url());
        console.log(postData);
        const test = postData + "&test=value";
        return request.continue({
          postData: test
        });
      }
    }
    request.continue();
  });
}

main();
```

I'm expecting that on each `POST` request that has `postData` - it will append `&test=value` to the arguments

**UPDATE:**

I solved it in a different way:
since the manipulated postData was not passing I ended up aborting the call using `request.abort()` and generating a new one using `page.evaluate(...fetch(...)...)` and only if the passed arguments are valid doing `request.continue()`.

It's working but I still don't know why the original

```js
    request.continue({
          postData: "...some-overide..."
        });
```

is not working